# How to check for duplicates while ignoring NAs (NA to value considered match)

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates, data.table, na

I want to know how best to check for duplicates but in a way that ignores NA values--i.e., if a value is compared to an NA, it is considered a match.

For example, if I have a dataset like such

```r
dt <- data.table(col1 = c("A", "B", NA, "A", "C", "C"), 
                 col2 = c("Z", "Y", "Z", NA, "X", "X"), 
                 col3 = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3))

dt

   col1 col2 col3
1:    A    Z    1
2:    B    Y    2
3: <NA>    Z    1
4:    A <NA>    1
5:    C    X    3
6:    C    X    3
```

I want row 5 and 6 to be flagged as a duplicate pair, but also rows 1 and 4. All the approaches I know only flag row 5 and 6.

e.g.,

```r
dupes_flagged <- dt %>%
  group_by(pick(1:3)) %>%
  mutate(
    dupe_group = cur_group_id()
  )

dupes_flagged
   col1 col2 col3 dupe_group
1:    A    Z    1          1
2:    B    Y    2          3
3: <NA>    Z    1          5
4:    A <NA>    1          2
5:    C    X    3          4
6:    C    X    3          4
```

```r
dt <- dt %>% as.data.table()
dup = duplicated(dt, by = c("col1", "col2", "col3"))
dt[, dupe_group := dup | c(tail(dup, -1), FALSE)]

dt
   col1 col2 col3 dupe_group
1:    A    Z    1      FALSE
2:    B    Y    2      FALSE
3: <NA>    Z    1      FALSE
4:    A <NA>    1      FALSE
5:    C    X    3       TRUE
6:    C    X    3       TRUE
```

Comment: I assume this is a toy example and that you won't always be searching on a single character for a match.  For example `NA` could match `Z` or `Fred` or 23 or anything, is that right?  Also, should 3 be a duplicate for 1 and 4?

Comment: why aren't 1 and 3 also duplicated

Answer (score 2):

A double `Reduce` produces a vector of whether a particular row has a duplicate, either exact or by `NA`.

```r
rowSums(sapply(dt2, function(col) {
  rowSums(sapply(seq_along(col), function(i) {
    replace(col, i, FALSE) %in% c(col[i], NA)
  })) > 0
})) > 0
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Introducing `NA` as being a wildcard, you'd need to compare all pairs of rows to identify duplicates: you can use `combn` to apply a function to all pairs of rows. To compare row-elements, you can use `==`, and check if `all` elements are equal, discarding `NA`s (`na.rm = FALSE`).

```r
cb <- combn(seq(nrow(dt)), m = 2, FUN = \(x){
  all(dt[x[1], ] == dt[x[2], ], na.rm = TRUE)
})
mat <- matrix(nrow = nrow(dt), ncol = nrow(dt))
mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- cb

#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA   NA
# [2,] FALSE    NA    NA    NA   NA   NA
# [3,]  TRUE FALSE    NA    NA   NA   NA
# [4,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE    NA   NA   NA
# [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE   NA   NA
# [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE   NA
```

Here, we see for instance that row 1 is duplicate with row 3 and 4, but not row 2.

What you eventually need is to know whether a row is duplicate with any other row:

```r
colSums(mat, na.rm = TRUE) > 0 | rowSums(mat, na.rm = TRUE) > 0
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```