# Is there a way to match individuals across rows in one dataframe?

Tags: r

I have data that looks similar to this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  LastName = c("Gamgee", "Gamgee", "Gamgey", "Baggins", "Baggins", NA, "The Gray"),
  FirstName = c("Sam", "Samwise", "Samuel", "Frodo the ring carrier", "Frodoh", "Smeagol", "Gandalf"), 
  DOB = c("2012-08-24", NA, "2012-08-24", NA, "01-31-2004", "05-15-2005", "11-02-1999")
)

df

> df
  LastName              FirstName        DOB
1   Gamgee                    Sam 2012-08-24
2   Gamgee                Samwise       <NA>
3   Gamgey                 Samuel 2012-08-24
4  Baggins Frodo the ring carrier       <NA>
5  Baggins                 Frodoh 01-31-2004
6     <NA>                Smeagol 05-15-2005
7 The Gray                Gandalf 11-02-1999
```

What I need to do is match names that seem to align... Maybe create clusters that group together names and DOBS's that the code has identified are similar? All I have found online is probabilistic matches across dataframes, so I am unsure how to conduct person-matching (for de-duplication purposes) within rows of the same df with variable/imperfectly matched names.

Potential output could look like this (but is malleable, only showing as an example output):

```
> df
  LastName              FirstName        DOB Cluster
1   Gamgee                    Sam 2012-08-24       1
2   Gamgee                Samwise       <NA>       1
3   Gamgey                 Samuel 2012-08-24       1
4  Baggins Frodo the ring carrier       <NA>       2
5  Baggins                 Frodoh 01-31-2004       2
6     <NA>                Smeagol 05-15-2005       3
7 The Gray                Gandalf 11-02-1999       4
```

It needs to be generalizable so direct name references (i.e. `str_detect("Sam")`) will not be an adequate solution to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking to "generalize" a culture- and language-sensitive language model on names in a way that not only recognizes acceptable shortened names (e.g., Charles/Chuck, William/Willy/Will/Billy/Bill), it also discards cognitively-intuitive distractors such as "the ring carrier". It should also be resilient to similar-enough-but-clearly-different, perhaps "Sam/Samuel" and "Samantha". (I recognize my examples all demonstrate my US upbringing, other examples in other languages/cultures surely exist.)

I suggest the most unambiguous path would be to use a dictionary of sorts, where you can prepopulate with known synonyms and expand as you find things.

For instance,

```r
synnames <- list(
  Samuel = c("Sam", "Samwise", "Samuel"),
  Frodo = c("Frodoh", "Frodo the ring carrier")
)

df$FirstName2 <- Reduce(
  function(firstname, sn) ifelse(firstname %in% synnames[[sn]], sn, firstname),
  names(synnames), init = df$FirstName)
df$Cluster <- match(df$FirstName2, unique(df$FirstName2))
df
#   LastName              FirstName        DOB FirstName2 Cluster
# 1   Gamgee                    Sam 2012-08-24     Samuel       1
# 2   Gamgee                Samwise       <NA>     Samuel       1
# 3   Gamgey                 Samuel 2012-08-24     Samuel       1
# 4  Baggins Frodo the ring carrier       <NA>      Frodo       2
# 5  Baggins                 Frodoh 01-31-2004      Frodo       2
# 6     <NA>                Smeagol 05-15-2005    Smeagol       3
# 7 The Gray                Gandalf 11-02-1999    Gandalf       4
```

This is currently ignoring `df$LastName`, so we need to work that in as well. You can either work them into the `synnames` as well, or you can make some inference (strong or weak?) with `stringdist::stringdist` or such. (I'll not demonstrate, I don't know that I suggest going down this route without a bit more research and knowledge of the dataset.) (This `stringdist` *may* be applied to first names as well. Again, context and nuances.)

Once you have normalized `LastName` as well, then you can assign them clusters with something like this summarization/merge:

```r
individuals <- unique(df[, c("LastName", "FirstName2")])
individuals$Cluster <- seq_len(nrow(individuals))
individuals
#   LastName FirstName2 Cluster
# 1   Gamgee     Samuel       1
# 3   Gamgey     Samuel       2
# 4  Baggins      Frodo       3
# 6     <NA>    Smeagol       4
# 7 The Gray    Gandalf       5

df <- merge(df, individuals, by = c("LastName", "FirstName2"), all.x = TRUE, sort = FALSE)
df
#   LastName FirstName2              FirstName        DOB Cluster
# 1   Gamgee     Samuel                    Sam 2012-08-24       1
# 2   Gamgee     Samuel                Samwise       <NA>       1
# 3   Gamgey     Samuel                 Samuel 2012-08-24       2
# 4  Baggins      Frodo Frodo the ring carrier       <NA>       3
# 5  Baggins      Frodo                 Frodoh 01-31-2004       3
# 6     <NA>    Smeagol                Smeagol 05-15-2005       4
# 7 The Gray    Gandalf                Gandalf 11-02-1999       5
```

Since you have `DOB`, you might always want to look for "sameness" in it, too, including it in `individuals`, though seeing the missing value in row 2 suggests you'll need leniency here. You might need loose-duplication-finding similar to [How to check for duplicates while ignoring NAs (NA to value considered match)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77910184/3358272) (a recent question).

This is not an easy task (normalizing names to find likely-duplicates), and it is fraught with peril and false-positives. Good luck.

Comment: I do agree, cultural differences definitely come into play... Unfortunately, I don't think this is feasible, my data has around 500 observations so I don't think this will be a valid method for me. I will try and match on other variables to make it a more robust match, thanks for the help.

Comment: Okay, you're choice. If this were me and I had 500 observations, I'd be all over this approach, it would start becoming problematic with 1000 plus. It might be a smaller footprint if you can reduce to the unique combinations (last/first) found and then look at _that_ dataset for doing this approach, it seems likely it would be a much smaller set. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, almost every row in my dataset has a duplicate as it contains data from multiple response agencies (like EMS, fire, dispatch), each of which documents inconsistently which is why I am slightly nervous to undertake a "dictionary"... Thank you again for the help and guidance, it is much appreciated.